How to remove function from "for" in Roblox Studio?
I have a code and I want the function to be on top, not in the loop itself. How do I do that?
local blocks = workspace.test:GetChildren()

for indx, obj in pairs(blocks) do
    obj.Touched:connect(function()
        wait(3)
        obj.BrickColor = BrickColor.Random()
    end)
end

I don't know how to do it...post how to do it right please

You can define a function as a variable, but the thing that makes this tricky is that you are interacting with the original object inside the function.
So the way to do this is with something called a higher-order function. We are going to use a function to create a function. And we will pass the result to the Touched connection.
local createOnTouchedFunction = function(originalObject)
    return function(otherObject)
        wait(3)
        originalObject.BrickColor = BrickColor.Random()
    end
end

local blocks = workspace.test:GetChildren()
for indx, obj in pairs(blocks) do
    obj.Touched:Connect(createOnTouchedFunction(obj))
end

Alternatively, you could connect the object inside the function :
local function changeColorOnTouch(obj)
    obj.Touched:Connect(function(otherObject)
        wait(3)
        obj.BrickColor = BrickColor.Random()
    end)
end

local blocks = workspace.test:GetChildren()
for indx, obj in pairs(blocks) do
    changeColorOnTouch(obj)
end

